# Max value for Javascript count function & submit on max

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, counter

I would like to limit this count function to only allow 3 items to be selected and submit it after 3 have been selected. I am using `ng-click="cuisine.selected = !cuisine.selected"` in my HTML.

```
$scope.select_cuisine = function(cuisine_id){
  var count=0;
  for (let i=0; i<$scope.cuisines.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.cuisines[i].selected) count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Increment or decrement a counter when an item is selected or unselected, respectevily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another `if` statement to check the `count`. If `count === 3`, then `return`.

```js
var cuisine = [true, false, false, true, false, true, false, false, true];

var countTilThree = function(cuisine) {
  var count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < cuisine.length; i++) {
    if (cuisine[i] === true)
      count++;
   
    if(count === 3)
      return count;
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(countTilThree(cuisine));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Create an array where you store your selections. On each selection, you check if it's already selected. If it's not, make sure the max isn't reached, and add it. If the item is already in the array (already selected), remove it from the array. That in turn sets it's length back by 1 so you can add another.

Here's a Demo:

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {

    $scope.selectedIds = [];
    $scope.selectCuisine = function(cuisine_id) {

      var idx = $scope.selectedIds.indexOf(cuisine_id);

      if (idx === -1) {
        // don't have the id, add operation

        if ($scope.selectedIds.length < 3) {
          // we're in range, do something with the selected ID
          $scope.selectedIds.push(cuisine_id);
        } else {
          // notify the user somehow
          console.warn('max selection reached');
        }
      } else {
        // already have the id, so we remove it
        $scope.selectedIds.splice(idx, 1);
      }
    }

  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="Controller">

    <button ng-click="selectCuisine(1)">Select 1</button>
    <button ng-click="selectCuisine(2)">Select 2</button>
    <button ng-click="selectCuisine(3)">Select 3</button>
    <button ng-click="selectCuisine(4)">Select 4</button>

    <h4 ng-show="selectedIds.length === 3">No more! Remove one first!</h4>

    <h4>Selected IDS</h4> {{ selectedIds }}

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way todo is disable the checkbox if number of current selected items is 3 and the item is not selected.

Everytime user select item, update $scope.count.

Set ng-enable='item.selected || count < 3'